# How to loop a data in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I want to loop my data Like this

**Like this**

[image: Like this]

**Not like this**

[image: Not like this]

My Controller:

```
function bills($patient_id){
    $data['payments'] = $this->model_patient->getpayments($patient_id);
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('billing', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

My Model: // joining my 3 tables, i want to display the procedures made by this patients and all the payments made.

```
function getpayments($patient_id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('treatmentrecord as tr');
    $this->db->join('patientprofile as pr','pr.patient_id = tr.patient_id');
    $this->db->join('billedrecord as br','br.treatment_id = tr.treatment_id');
    $this->db->where('tr.patient_id', $patient_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

My View:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Procedures</td>
        <td>Payments</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($payments as $payments): ?>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $payments->procedures; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $payments->bill_paid; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach ?>

</table>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

OP:
    Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [treatment_id] => 1
            [procedures] => ProcedureName1
            [patient_id] => 1
            [bill_id] => 3
            [bill_paid] => 500
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [treatment_id] => 5
        [procedures] => ProcedureName3
        [patient_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 4
        [bill_paid] => 2323
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [treatment_id] => 1
        [procedures] => ProcedureName1
        [patient_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 5
        [bill_paid] => 2555
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [treatment_id] => 6
        [procedures] => ProcedureName2
        [patient_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 6
        [bill_paid] => 2555
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [treatment_id] => 1
        [procedures] => ProcedureName1
        [patient_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 7
        [bill_paid] => 23232
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [treatment_id] => 5
        [procedures] => ProcedureName3
        [patient_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 8
        [bill_paid] => 2323
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First sort the `$payments` with respect to `procedures` like below:

**Snippet:**

```
usort($payments,function($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a->procedures,$b->procedures);
});
```

- Now, you can take help of the index of the element while looping. So if it's first index or name doesn't match with previous index, just print it, else print an empty string.

**Snippet:**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Procedures</td>
        <td>Payments</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($payments as $index => $payment): ?>


<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $index === 0 || $payment->procedures != $payments[$index - 1]->procedures  ? $payment->procedures : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?= $payment->bill_paid; ?></td>

    </tr>


</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I tried but still have the same output

Comment: @Musk Can you show the exact code you tried? Also, is $payments associative in nature?

Comment: the code you gave

Comment: @Musk Can you show how $payments looks like? Share using `var_export($payments)`.

Comment: check the post. i already added it

Comment: @Musk I am getting the results as expected at my end. https://imgur.com/a/E1fvxCl

Comment: @Musk Ohh, your `procedures` aren't ordered. Wait, I will fix. Hence, you should always show your input data.

Answer (score 0):

**controller**

```
function bills($patient_id){
    $payments = $this->model_patient->getpayments($patient_id);

    $result = array();
        foreach ($payments as $element) {
            $result[$element->treatment_id][] = $element;
        }

    $data['payments'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('billing', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

**view**

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Procedures</td>
                <td>Payments</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($payments as $index => $payment) {
                foreach ($payment as $key => $pay) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            if ($key == 0) {
                                echo $pay->procedures;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $pay->bill_paid; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: the problem to this is the procedure will not display if no payments is made by that procedure