# How to hide if result is same on cell (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have question how to print the result of

```
A | 1
A | 2
A | 3
B | 1
B | 2
```

to be like this

```
A | 1
  | 2
  | 3
B | 1
  | 2
```

Hide if value of recordset on `while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {}` is same value on td cell
Thanks. 
-edit 
no, example on column 1, 2, 3 which row1 may same value with row2 for column1 and column2 but next row it possible to presentate that column1 is still same with prrvious row but column2 change (not same) at it all column3 are unique it is about 3 columns with many rows but duplicate value on column1 and 2 not 3

Comment: If you are sure that all your `A` and `B` are group together, just use a var to test if you need to print it or not. Eg : before the loop `$test = ''`, then in your while loop : `if ($test !== the_value_A_or_B) { echo the_value_A_or_B; $test=the_value_A_or_B;}`

Comment: Just edit your question please with the content of `var_dump($rs)` please so we know how it looks like. And add you try with the loop to echo so we can have a base to work with :)

Comment: This is what is called a [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break). You need your data to be properly sorted by the values of the first column, and then you need to simply check inside your loop, whether the value of that column for the current record, is still the same as for the previous one. If they are not, then you output the value in the first column, otherwise just a blank/nothing.

Comment: Duplicate of  [How to loop a data in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889416/how-to-loop-a-data-in-php)

Comment: no, it is not only abc, inside table tr td may same date loop but I want only one if other is same on next row it exclude not show display in td

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding all values to an array and then printing it.

Add values:

```
$result = [];
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {
    $result[$rs['col1']][] = $rs['col2'];
}
```

Print values:

```
foreach($result as $name => $item) {
    echo $name  . " | " . $item[0] . "\n";
    for($i = 1; $i < count($item); $i++) {
        echo "  | " . $item[$i] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6b1012d0d3f4b72b647f0177249167788756ce9), slightly modified to run in an isolated environment, but overall the logic is the same.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you should be arrang the results in array

```
$res = [];
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {
    $res[$rs['alphabate_column']][] = $rs['col2'];        
}
```

this code for your output

```
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($res as $alphabate=>$val){

        foreach($val as $key=>$val2){
echo '<tr>';
            if($key == 0){
                echo "<td>$alphabate  </td>";
            }else{
                echo " <td></td>";
            }
           echo "<td> $val2 </td>";

        echo '</tr>';
}
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: This is just copied and deoptimized version of my answer. Why are you posting answers if you are just going to post the same thing?

Comment: this is not a copy version

Comment: Compare both code and tell me. If you again says that this is copied than I delete it. I think this is just another version of code

Comment: You literally copied my answer, changed some of the text and deoptimized by adding more code in the inner `foreach`. Do you want to know why it is deoptimized?

Comment: @benipr explain more what you want

Comment: imagine datasheet table tr td with date column and description, the date at row may same with different description but it print loop 01.01.19 next row 01.01.19 and so on. it should be not print again at next row tr td because still same with previous row or rs

Comment: @benipr This is just an example. Arrange variables according to your requirements

Comment: yes thank you i will try first and will let you know if i can do that. thanks.